# How to optimize queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql query for search is :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_tb WHERE location ='{$location}' AND price BETWEEN '$minprice' AND '$maxprice' ")or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); ;
```

This makes a compulsion to enter both the location and min and max price in form.
I want a query that can make user to enter either location or max and min price, as well as allow user to search by both fields. What should i do?

Comment: What did you tried when solving your question? Provide some code, please.

Comment: You can check availability of those values(location, minprice and maxprice) in PHP code and then generate query string respectively. This is better than using conditions in MySQL query. If you want more specific answer, just post some code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thsi ought to do it for you :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM room_tb ";

if($location){
$query .= " WHERE location ='{$location}' ";
}

if(($minprice)&&($maxprice)&&(!$location)){
$query .= " WHERE price BETWEEN '$minprice' AND '$maxprice'";
}

if(($minprice)&&($maxprice)&&($location)){
$query .= " AND price BETWEEN '$minprice' AND '$maxprice'";
}

$result = mysql_query($query)or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

When I am generating my queries with optional fields, I create an array of each field, then join them with `implode`

```
$query_array = array();
$queries_stringed = '';

if(strlen($location) > 0){
    $query_array[] = "location ='{$location}'";
};
if(strlen($minprice) > 0 && strlen($maxprice) > 0){
    $query_array[] = "(price BETWEEN '$minprice' AND '$maxprice')";
};
if(!empty($query_array)){
    $queries_stringed = "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $query_array);
};

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_tb $queries_stringed");
```

Comment: You'll want to make sure `$queries_stringed` isn't empty before you run the query, or you'll get a query error.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to those answers - you shouldn't trust users inputs and should escape given strings or use PDO instead of mysql_ functions